# Can SimplePie grab images from feeds

Tags: php, import, rss, feed, simplepie

I am using this simplepie and i have uploaded the files to my host. Everything seems to be working fine except one thing. The blog that i'm getting the feed from has images in it, and when i use the simplepie to view the feed, the images don't show up. Is there a way to get the images to show up when i view the blog with simplepie?

Okay i am sorry, i am new at this. I am just using the code straight from the website to try and view the blog. i will put the code at the bottom here. So yea like i said i'm just trying to get the images to show up that are on the blog i'm reading from. Everything shows up great except that.

--- Header Information ---

```
<?php

// Make sure SimplePie is included. You may need to change this to match the location of simplepie.inc.
require_once('simplepie.inc');

// We'll process this feed with all of the default options.
$feed = new SimplePie();

// Set the feed to process.
$feed->set_feed_url('http://wordpress.homickdesign.com/feed/');

// Run SimplePie.
$feed->init();

// This makes sure that the content is sent to the browser as text/html and the UTF-8 character set (since we didn't change it).
$feed->handle_content_type();

// Let's begin our XHTML webpage code.  The DOCTYPE is supposed to be the very first thing, so we'll keep it on the same line as the closing-PHP tag.
?>
```

--- Code ---

```
<h2><a href="<?php echo $feed->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $feed->get_description(); ?></a><br />
      <span>Latest news from Robert Homick</span></h2>       

        <?php
$c=1;   
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
if($c <= 3){
?>

        <p><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a><br />
        <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?><br />
        <span>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></span><br />
        <?php $c++;?>


<?php } endforeach;  ?>
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you post your source code.  Yes, SimplePie gets media elements, but some types can be tricky.

Comment: ok i added the code, i'm sorry i am new for this stuff.

Comment: you should accept one Muskies's answer

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can call get_content() and the entire post or the portion of the post that is included in the feed will be outputted to the screen, all the HTML tags included. If you want to pull say the first image in the post, you have to do a little more work, here is what I've been doing.

```
$htmlDOM = new simple_html_dom();
$htmlDOM->load($item->get_content());
$image = $htmlDOM->find('img', 0); 
$html .= '<img src="thumbnail.php?file=' . $image->src . '&maxw=300&maxh=300" border="0" />';
```

That snippet from my current little project, uses simple_html_dom and another script I got off the Internet to resize images on the fly. If you just want to display the image not resize it at all $image->src is the URL. I think functionality like this may be added to SimplePie in the future or an add-on to SimplePie, but in the mean time, it is four lines of code to display the first image from an item from a feed.

Comment: I can't seem to get `$htmlDOM  = new simple_html_dom();` to return anything (I'm including https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/blob/master/simple_html_dom.php).

Comment: I doubt I am running the latest code, but if $htmlDOM is not returning anything maybe your feed is empty or contains no HTML. Having worked extensively with RSS feeds often they do not follow the standard, if you have garbage going in, you get garbage coming out. Simple HTML DOM and SimplePie undoubtably do some error checking but there is text that likely gives them grief, I wrote my own error condition handling code on top and still things keep changing, both Pinterest and YouTube have made changes. YouTube has an all new API I have to learn...

Comment: That code snippet was taken right off my home page, so the code is still running, like I said, YouTube is no longer supporting some old API code, so I must investigate that further after my exams, but that code definitely did work and may still be working on my personal website www.muschamp.ca, what feed are you trying it on, is it actually RSS and which version of the RSS standard, does the feed itself validate?

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/extending-simplepie-to-parse-unique-rss-feeds/) will help you to embed images in simple pie output.